# Use certain object based on the property of another object

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a box. In the box are bricks. The brick have a position, size and a color. 
but the color is defined separatly, because I also have other kind of items with an color.

the objects are:

```
class Color:
    __init__(self, name, colorcode):
        self.name = name
        self.color = colorcode

    def dosomething(self):
        pass

class Brix:
    __init__(self, size, position, colorname):
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.colorname = colorname
```

and I have a certain function where I need a link between brix and the colorcode. for example:

```
def change_brix(brixs):
    some work around to link link the colors and brixs
    return colorcode[::2]/2
```

how can I link the colors to the brixs in my function?

```
a = [Brix(10,2,'blue'),Brix(10,3,'blue'),Brix(11,2,'red')]
b = [color('blue', 11100), color('red', 12100), color('orange', 11300)]
```

in my case the color objects have many arguments so i don't want to define them in all my  Brix object.
Maybe it could be solved with inherited objects but I do not understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Set the relation through making your `Brix` class constructor accept an instance of `Color` class to conveniently access its attributes:

```
class Brix:
    def __init__(self, size, position, color):
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.color_obj = color   # Color instance 


colors = [color('blue', 11100), color('red', 12100), color('orange', 11300)]
brixes = [Brix(10,2, colors[0]), Brix(10,3, colors[0]), Brix(11,2, colors[1])]
```